# Как составить более элегантный алгоритм обхода строки по индексам?

Tags: алгоритм, golang

В тексте, при помощи суффиксного массива выделил индексы, в данной момент мой алгоритм обхода выглядит так, уверен,что имеются более элегантные версии при помощи классических алгоритмнов.

```
str := `Уж небо осенью дышало Уж реже солнышко блистало`
buff := bytes.Buffer{}
buff.WriteString(str)
searchIndex := []byte("Уж")
index := suffixarray.New(buff.Bytes())
offset := index.Lookup(searchIndex, -1)
sort.Ints(offset)
l := len(offset)
sliceOfBytes := make([][]byte, l)
for iter := 0; l > 0; iter++ {
    if l == 1 {
        sliceOfBytes[iter] = buff.Next(offset[len(offset)-1])
        break
    }
    sliceOfBytes[iter] = buff.Next(offset[iter+1] - offset[iter])
    l--
}

for _, s := range sliceOfBytes {
    fmt.Println(string(s))
}
//Уж небо осенью дышало 
//Уж реже солнышко блистало
```

Comment: Нельзя ли поподробнее объяснить, в чём состоит задача? Что такое `обход строки по индексам`?

Comment: @Mbo имеется к примеру строки  "Привет Андрей\nПриключения Буратино\nПричуды в придверии праздника" и идёт выобрка индексов по суффуксу "При" в независимости от регистра и возвращаются в отсортированном массиве. Соответсвенно разница между индексами это слова, вот их и вывести.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив эту информацию, а также покажите, что получится в результате.

Comment: @MBo отредактировал.

Comment: А если просто искать подстроку функциями Index** ? Или Split (он удалит подстроку-разделитель, но ведь её можно заново добавить)